# blogengine without php or asp.net etc

Tags: javascript, html, blogs

Is there a way to have a blog directly integrated into my HTML/javascript-only website, without having to have something like a SQL-database and a dynamic engine like PHP or MySQL?

Maybe there is some service in the web that offers this (hopefully without ads :) ). Or maybe I can have a blog engine entirely written in javasript?

Answer (score 3):

Entirely written in JavaScript?  Surely that defeats the entire point of having a "blog-engine" in the first place?  The point being that the data is stored somewhere and dynamically retrieved.  To avoid using anything server-side (which seems to be your intent), and only use HTML/JavaScript, you'd have to store all the data for the blog in files that are served up to each visitor, and then retrieve the data from the particular, local, locations using JavaScript.

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding the point here... but this seems to be an utterly useless way of trying to go about things.  Blogs are, in general, either written statically (in HTML [even though this is rare]), or are dynamically generated from a database by a server-side scripting language (most common).

**Edit:** As an additional point, I suppose you could include some third-party blog feed, or service, in your page, via use of JavaScript... but I'm unsure as to which (if any) blogging services would directly support this method of working.  Additionally, this is quite an unreliable way of including third-party data in a page...

Comment: There is a service called FeedBurner which allows you, among other things, to embed javascript on a page and have that script pull in the feed data.

Comment: True enough, but as I said in my edit, this isn't a very reliable way of retrieving third-party data, especially with FeedBurner (as a specific example) experiencing a lot of downtime, lately.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a thought. It's not really a blog engine - but a wiki.

Entirely javascript/html/css. All lives in a single html file:

http://www.tiddlywiki.com/

not sure how it would work on a real live site, but their site is using it:

> ```
> * A personal notebook
> * A GTD ("Getting Things Done") productivity tool
> * A collaboration tool
> * For building websites (this site is a TiddlyWiki file!)
> * For rapid prototyping
> * ...and much more!
> ```

Comment: TiddlyWiki is great, but it can become a headache when the size of the file bloats. It would be nice if there was something similar that hosted the individual tiddlers in separate files.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [github pages](http://github.com/blog/272-github-pages). You will get a generated blog with version control.

Answer (score 2):

Other option is to use a Desktop blog tool and then update your site.

You can user [iWeb](http://www.apple.com/ilife/iweb/) if you have a Mac or [CityDesk](http://www.fogcreek.com/CityDesk/) on Windows or you may try this [open source tool](http://thingamablog.sourceforge.net/)

**Edit** Today I came across this tool: [Zeta producer](http://www.zeta-producer.com/index.html) that may help.

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/showdown-blog/
Blog engine written in just JS and XML [v0.6] {JavaScript, XML}

Answer (score 1):

So, what you want is to have a blog where you're website provider doesn't provide a way to serve dynamic content?

The only way I see that you can do it in that case is writing html-files (or text-files if you prefer) and adding them to the site. After that you can have some JavaScript to add them to your "blog-page".

You of course need to upload them to the website in the same way as you do for the other files, and then have a way for the JavaScript to know which pages it should fetch.

I am not aware of any JavaScript blog-engines, but you can have a look at the templating functions in for instance [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/template)

Of course, that means that you will have to fetch both the template and the content through Ajax and let the client do all the processing (could be slow and possibly insecure), and you still need to have a place to upload the content and update it.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be using a generator to create the HTML/CSS/JS to upload to your server, take a look at Webby: http://webby.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

IF you really need to you can use a public api for a service that lets you post small bits of info and retrieve it using javascript.

for example if you only need small posts you can make a blog in html.javascript that utilizes twitter as the engine. of course you will be limited to 140 chars. I am sure there are other services that will allow a similar idea but with less restrictions.

And of course the best option - Get a blog software or host your blog with a service provider and link to it from you site.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use some application that generates the static web pages of your blog, and uploads them to your web server.  This way you'd have a blog with static content that could all be managed in javascript alongside your existing site, without needing to install database, daemon software, or additional dynamic web programming languages on your server.  The static content generation could happen directly on your server if possible, or you could run the html generation tool locally and upload the output.

MoveableType has a tool like this.  You still need somewhere to store the content of your blog, and for this MoveableType uses MySQL by default, so you'd still need to install a database somewhere, but the database could simply be one your local desktop.

MoveableType also has support via plugins or older versions that can retrieve data from a sqlite or other database.  The advantage of sqlite is that it doesn't require installing daemons like MySQL does, you can just put a sqlite file on disk somewhere, give MoveableType the path to the file, and run the script to generate your static content.

There are likely other tools like MoveableType, and I have in the past generated blog-like web pages simply by writing small scripts to generate HTML.  The main issue is just that you need somewhere for these scripts to fetch data from.

Another option might be to develop your blog using XSLT, ... with XSLT, you'd put the content of your pages in XML files, and then write a template in XSL that converts your XML to HTML.

If you google for 'static blog site generation' you might find other ideas/options, including Jekyll/github mentioned in one of the other responses.